# Latest shapefiles of Indian states

Tags: shapefile, data, vector, india

I need shapefiles of Indian states that of 2011 which has almost 671 districts of India. Can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 1):

The [**Datameet github repo for maps**](https://github.com/datameet/maps/) has the 640 districts as per the 2011 census, which are available under a [Creative Commons Attribution-ShareAlike 2.5 India license](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.5/in/), in shapefile format.

I don't know where you got the figure of 671, but according to census of India, there were 640 districts in 2011. (see page 14 of the [Administrative Atlas](http://www.censusindia.gov.in/2011census/maps/administrative_maps/Final%20Atlas%20India%202011.pdf))

Comment: Thanks for the reply and sorry for the mistake.Can you please tell me How to download the shape file from there.

Comment: If you go to the Github Repo, you'll see a "download Zip" button on the right hand column. Just click on that, to get a Zip of the entire repo, which includes the data that you want.